# Is the ETH in this Address Mine to Claim? Etherscan Shows Balance Left

Tags: etherscan, addresses, balances, binance

I was wondering if someone could help me understand some confusing situation with a Binance ETH address I have. I was going through my records and noticed that one of the addresses I have used in the past still has over 0.06 ETH and some ERC20 tokens (the dollar value of everything is around $200, so not an insignificant amount) according to Etherscan. Here is a screenshot of the page:

[image]
This address has only 9 transactions in total, all from Dec. 2017 to May 2018.

7 of those transactions are inputs or deposits and 2 are withdrawals, as the image shows. I determined it is a Binance address because every single one of the incoming ETH into this account match with ETH deposits on my Binance account. However, the withdrawals don't match with the reports from my Binance account.

Etherscan marks those withdrawals as going to "Binance" which is an address with thousands of ETH.

At the same time, my ETH balance on Binance shows 0.00000000, but I am wondering if this is some amount that I somehow still have a claim over. The account only has my activity and nothing has moved since May 2018. Is there something I can do here, or at least some possible explanation about what this means?

Thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: There's nothing you can do without the private key. If you think it is your Binance wallet you might ask their customer support.

Comment: I might try contacting them and see if it leads to anything, but more than anything just wanted to learn more about the way the exchange handles balances in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a Binance *deposit* address, so I assume you don't actually have the private keys for this address. Binance may decide at their own discretion to transfer those funds into their hot/cold exchange wallet - those are the 2 outgoing transactions labeled with the recipient address "Binance".

As you say, the deposits credited to your exchange account match the deposits made to this deposit address, so all the funds are accounted for. If you sum up the transaction in vs. out amounts, you will see, that Binance decided to leave some ether behind (maybe to pay for future gas fees). So the remaining ETH balance is not yours (since it was already credited to the exchange account).

Same probably goes for the ERC-20 tokens. If they are from airdrops, it depends if Binance will credit a specific airdrop to their customers - if so, you will have gotten a credit on your exchange account. But most exchanges don't credit airdrops.

Comment: I was thinking along the same way. I guess I just wanted to get more clarity about how Binance uses those deposit addresses. Thanks.

Comment: @AndresBerejnoi My Binance deposit address also still has a balance of 0.3 ETH, so actually a lot of money. They never moved it to their "storage" wallet. But of course it was credited to me on my exchange account. You can take a look at the wallets with a 'Binance' label on Etherscan (https://etherscan.io/accounts/label/binance). I think they probably have a minimum balance at which they start to move the funds to one of their storage wallets.